# Texture painting onto a curved object

Tags: texture-painting

[image]I'm texture painting a pipe but as it's curved, the brush leaves a hard lines where the view and angle of camera and brush stops it reaching. How can I paint directly onto the flat texture that wraps around the object so it paints more seamlessly? Thank you.

Comment: Sounds like you forgot to unwrap your object properly. How does your UVs look like? https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/meshes/editing/uv.html

Comment: what happens if you change your view angle, is there still a problem?

Comment: You can texture paint onto your unwrapped UV map rather than directly on the object. See Andrew Price's video [here](https://youtu.be/nht2RoYBUfA?list=PLjEaoINr3zgEq0u2MzVgAaHEBt--xLB6U&t=90).

Comment: Thanks for your replies. The UV map looks fine and I have tried painting on the map itself. I thought by adding more vertices it would help but it didn't.

Comment: We'll need to see the .blend file in that case by uploading to [blend-exchange.com](https://blend-exchange.com/). Have you checked the normals of your object?

Comment: You can turn off Occlude and Backface Culling to allow your paint to go through the object, possibly allowing the paint to ease across the tube - but another option altogether could be to use the Fill tool using the gradient with a Line stroke.